# how to check if schema contains is array of strings or array of struct in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have dataframe with below schema

```
root
 |-- array_column: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- label_info: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- extras: string (nullable = true)
```

How can i find programatically that my schema has column of array of string or array of struct. Above is just sample schema. I will have dynamic schema.

Till now i could do something like this

```
if isinstance(df.schema["array_column"].dataType, ArrayType):
```

But this only tells the column is of arraytype.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your column is an array column, you can access the schema of the elements of it with elementType. Then you can check for the Type of those elements like this:

```
if isinstance(df.schema["array_column"].dataType.elementType, StringType):
```